# Having problems with an AppleScript

Tags: applescript

This isn't launching FaceTime when I want it to! I want it to launch an app, and you get to choose what app it launches, so if I press Google Chrome, then it launches Google Chrome, but it doesn't launch FaceTime.

```
set the_results to (display dialog "Please Choose User!" buttons {"Admin", "Guest", "Cancel"})
set button_returned to button returned of the_results
if button_returned is "Guest" then display dialog "Guest is not functioning!"
if button_returned is "Admin" then display dialog "Please insert password!" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2 default answer "" cancel button 1 with hidden answer
if the text returned of the result is "Test" then
    set the_results to (display dialog "Welcome! What would you like to do?" buttons {"Chrome", "Messages", "More"})
    set button_returned to button returned of the_results
    if button_returned is "Chrome" then tell application "Google Chrome"
        activate
    end tell
    if button_returned is "Messages" then tell application "Messages"
        activate
    end tell
    if button_returned is "More" then display dialog "Second Page" buttons {"FaceTime", "Thank You!"}
end if
if button_returned is "FaceTime" then tell application "FaceTime"
    activate
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a similar error as in your [last question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226466/applescript-help):

You can either reuse *button_returned* and *the_results* (like you already did in line 6 and 7 <-> 1 and 2):

```
...
    if button_returned is "More" then set the_results to (display dialog "Second Page" buttons {"FaceTime", "Thank You!"})
    set button_returned to button returned of the_results
end if
if button_returned is "FaceTime" then tell application "FaceTime"
    activate
end tell
```

or introduce two new variables: *button_returned2* and *the_nextresults*:

```
...
    if button_returned is "More" then set the_nextresults to (display dialog "Second Page" buttons {"FaceTime", "Thank You!"})
    set button_returned2 to button returned of the_nextresults
end if
if button_returned2 is "FaceTime" then tell application "FaceTime"
    activate
end tell
```